# Criar novo Registro

Tags: javascript

Bom dia a todos. Seria possível utilizando javascript ao entrar em uma pagina, automaticamente criar uma nova coluna em uma tabela no banco de dados ? Seria algo assim: O usuário entra na página e já recebe um número de atendimento e caso ele saia da pagina sem concluir faria um rollback apagando esse registro não iniciado no banco de dados.

Essa é a página que eu tenho:

```
 <body onload="salvaBancoAjax()">

 <!-- main -->
  <main class="container">
   <!-- messages -->
  //aqui deveria entrar o id registrado
  <center><h1><i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></h1></i><br><br><h2>
   Atendimento numero <input class="o-form__data" name="id" type="text"> 
   </h2></center>

</div>
 </div>
</main>
<!-- ./main -->
<br>
<br>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
//este é o ajax

 <script type="text/javascript">

function salvaBancoAjax() {
let url = 'php/adiciona-atendimento.php' + '/json';
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status = 200)
            preencheCampos(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

function preencheCampos(json) {
document.querySelector('input[name=id]').value = json.id;

 }

 </script>

<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap-4.0.0/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap-4.0.0/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: sim, só colocar o código javascript do DocumenReady para ser executado quando a página estiver carregada

Comment: ola Ricardo editei o post mostrando que o que preciso é automaticamente a inserção do dado (id) será efetuada e as informações serão sem que a página recarregue. Mas não estou conseguindo executar o script. obrigado